# Can I call this graph as a gaussian?

Tags: gaussian

My program is a chatbot. It has rule to represent the state that user is talking to the bot at node level `n`. I have 1 to 9 nodes in the application. Here is the summary of each states

```
1    3331
2    695 
3    1381
4    945 
5    1754
6    5303
7    2235
8    1664
9    3844
Name: visited, dtype: int64
```

[image: Last application state]

If number 1 and 9 is not too high. I will not have a question.

**Question:**
Is it safe to call this distribution as a gaussian?

Comment: Not even close.

Comment: How on earth can it be a Guassian when it isn't even a continuous distribution, its a discrete distribution on the integers 1 to 9? And asking "is it safe" is meaningless since we have *no idea* what inference you are going to make based on this distributional assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you left out the large blue and yellow peaks, then maybe. Otherwise, no.

With all three distinct peaks, you might call it a multi-modal Guassian - meaning it  is a mixture of three standard Gaussian distributions. This illustrates the idea:

[image: Guassian mixture]

**Important:** As pointed out by *Spacedman* in the comments, this comparison would only strictly apply if the data itself could be approximated as a continuous variable. This would mean you x-axis variable (*state*) should not be discrete. If the values were put in bins and your graph were therefore a histogram of the underlying data. Please have a look at [this question for more details](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125552/draw-a-histogram-with-normal-distribution-overlay).

---

We can normally describe the distributions as being **fat-tailed**, when the extremes on the left and right of the curve don't ever really head towards zero, but seeing as your curve really shoots up again at both ends, I don't think it would be a useful description here.

Comment: The data are both *discrete* and *truncated* so its nothing like a mixture of Gaussians, or Poisson. Please don't give bad statistical advice.

Comment: @Spacedman - agreed, I admit only answering visually. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Also, look at the Y-axis. This plot comes from about 20,000 samples. *If* these were coming from N(a,b) and discretised then the uncertainty on those bars would be tiny, the histogram would look *much more* like a discretised Gaussian distribution.  Maybe if this was from 200 or 100 samples you couldn't reject that hypothesis, but looking at this I can instantly say "This is *not* from a Gaussian distribution" (even ignoring the top and bottom bins).